# How to group an array of objects by name and sum

Tags: swift

For example:

```
        [Test(count: 5, name: "Ivan", innerNumber: "123123"),
         Test(count: 5, name: "Ivan", innerNumber: "123123"),
         Test(count: 10, name: "Miko", innerNumber: "4312432"),
         Test(count: 10, name: "Miko", innerNumber: "4312432")]
```

I want to group an array by `name` field and sum by `count` field

As a result, I want an array in the form:

```
        [Test(count: 10, name: "Ivan", innerNumber: "123123"),
         Test(count: 20, name: "Miko", innerNumber: "4312432")]
```

Comment: Use Dictionary(grouping:by:) where you group by name, then calculate total count for each entry in the dictionary and create a new Test with the total and the unique name. Then you need to decide what to do if innerNumber is not unique for the group

Comment: You can write some sample code as it looks like. You can ignore the innerNumber field.

Comment: I have given you an idea how to do it, why not try yourself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make sure your collection is sorted by name and use reduce to accumulate the count value:

```
let grouped: [Test] = tests.sorted(by: {$0.name < $1.name}).reduce(into: []){
    if let last = $0.last, last.name == $1.name,
        last.innerNumber == $1.innerNumber {
        $0[$0.indices.last!] = .init(count: last.count + $1.count, name: last.name, innerNumber: last.innerNumber)
    } else {
        $0.append($1)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! looks laconic!

Answer (score 0):

`Dictionary(grouping:by:)` works great for this:

```
struct Test: Hashable {
    let count: Int
    let name: String
    let innerNumber: String // Well that's not really a number, is it 
}

let input = [
    Test(count: 5, name: "Ivan", innerNumber: "123123"),
    Test(count: 5, name: "Ivan", innerNumber: "123123"),
    Test(count: 10, name: "Miko", innerNumber: "4312432"),
    Test(count: 10, name: "Miko", innerNumber: "4312432"),
]

let output = Dictionary(grouping: input, by: \.name)
    .map { name, tests -> Test in
        let sum = tests.lazy.map(\.count).reduce(0, +)
        
        // Assumes that all tests with the same name also have the same innerNumber.
        // You might want to verify that with an assertion.
        let innerNumber = tests.first!.innerNumber
        
        return Test(count: sum, name: name, innerNumber: innerNumber)
    }

for test in output {
    print(test)
}
```